# Computing $5^{5^{5^{5^{5}}}}$ mod $100000=10^5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a convenient way to compute $5^{5^{5^{5^{5}}}}$ mod $100000=10^5$ using elementary  number theory? I tried to find some similar questions, for example the followings:
[Computing $7^{13} \mod 40$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149062/computing-713-mod-40),
[Computing $22^{201} \mod (30)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146165/computing-22201-mod-30),
[Modular exponentiation by hand ($a^b\bmod c$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/modular-exponentiation-by-hand-ab-bmod-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I think the methods in the links are not suitable in this case. Any hints?

Comment: Do you know Euler's Totient Theorem (generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem)?

Comment: Yes, the methods from the linked threads apply. Use the fact that $10^5=5^5\cdot 2^5$. Your number is manifestly divisible by $5^5$, so one plan would be to find its remainder modulo $2^5$, and then apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes I do

Comment: Maybe also $5^{5\cdot5}\bmod10^5=(5^5\bmod10^5)^5\bmod10^5$ might be way transform the exponents?

Comment: Basically all you need to do is to observe that $5^8\equiv1\pmod{32}$. Therefore you need the remainder of $5^{5^{5^5}}$ modulo $8$. But $5^2\equiv1\pmod8$ and the exponent $5^5$ is odd.

Comment: Try things like $a^{a^a}=(a^a)^{a^{a-1}}$